# Gamer Monitors Not Working Properly with Mac Mini Late 2018

Tags: macos, display, mac-mini, hdmi, displayport

I have a 2018 Mac Mini Late and for a few years I have noticed strange behavior on monitors.

When I turn on the monitor and then the Mac, the monitor displays "No Signal" messages as if the Mac is not turned on, but if I enter the password (without seeing the login screen), the monitor detects the Mac and the screen appears, but if the Mac goes to sleep, just forcing the reboot to get back to work, always turning on the Mac first and then the monitor.

The most curious thing is that I noticed this problem only on gaming monitors, with a refresh rate greater than 60Hz.

In 2020 I was using the LG 34' 144Hz 4UC79G-B, via HDMI > HDMI and this problem occurred frequently, almost every day.

In 2021 I decided to opt for a professional monitor from Dell, with only 60Hz (Monitor Dell Professional P2314H 23'), I connected it with a USB-C to DisplayPort cable and this problem never occurred, it worked perfectly.

This year I switched to a larger monitor, the Asus TUF 27' 165 Hz - 1ms VG279QR, I used the same USB-C cable for DisplayPort and the problem recurred, I turn on the monitor, then the Mac and it has no signal, or it comes on suspended and lose signal until restarted or enter password without seeing.

What could be happening to have this problem? Will it be the refresh rate, response time or something else?